# VueJS - Can we prevent component rendering using Composition?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Until now I was using a computed property with a v-if in my component to avoid it to render if basic props was not given, for example :

```
<template>
  <div v-if="basicPropsProvided">
      Blabla
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  props: {
    icon: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    url: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  computed: {
    basicPropsProvided(): boolean {
      return !!this.title && !!this.icon && !!this.url
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to move this logic to the setup method, without success. Do you think there is a way to do this with the composition api to reuse the logic on other components ?

Comment: What did you try out ?

Comment: How do you expect it to work? Please, describe how exactly should happen if basicPropsProvided is false. *I tried to move this logic to the setup method, without success* - again, what did you try, and what did not work? It's easier to point out a mistake rather than write the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: @EstusFlask if the computed is false, the component is not rendered due to the v-if

Comment: This is what Suspense is for. So yes, it's possible to solve this via composition. But this doesn't cover the case when it becomes false once again

Answer (score 1):

Define a composable function called `useCheckProvidedProps` which takes props as parameter and returns the computed property :

```
<template>
  <div v-if="basicPropsProvided">
      Blabla
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import  {computed} from 'vue'
function useCheckProvidedProps (props){

return {
    basicPropsProvided:computed(()=>!!props.title && !!props.icon && !!props.url)
}
}
export default{
  props: {
    icon: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    url: { type: String, required: true }
  },
 setup(props){
  const {basicPropsProvided}=useCheckProvidedProps (props)

     return {basicPropsProvided}

}

}
</script>
```

Comment: that's a way, but hardly reusable. Do you think we can get rid of the v-if ?

Comment: You could define that composable function in separate file and reuse it